# C++ Windows notification: Use of dependent template name

Tags: c++, windows, templates, notifications

I'm currently trying to create a callback for Windows 10 native notification. My code for adding notification looks following:

```
notification->add_Dismissed(
    Callback<Implements<RuntimeClassFlags<ClassicCom>,
    ITypedEventHandler<ToastNotification*, ToastDismissedEventArgs*>>>(

    [eventHandler, expirationTime](IToastNotification*, IToastDismissedEventArgs* e) {

        ToastDismissalReason reason;
        if (SUCCEEDED(e->get_Reason(&reason))) {
            if (reason == ToastDismissalReason_UserCanceled &&
                expirationTime &&
                MyDateTime::Now() >= expirationTime
            ){
                reason = ToastDismissalReason_TimedOut;
            }

            eventHandler->toastDismissed(static_cast<IWinToastHandler::WinToastDismissalReason>(reason));
        }

        return S_OK;
}).Get(), &dismissedToken);
```

Where `notification` is `IToastNotification*` and `eventHandler` is my custom handler class.

However since last Visual Studio update, I'm getting following errors:

```
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt\wrl\event.h(316): error C7510: 'Callback': use of dependent template name must be prefixed with 'template'
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt\wrl\event.h(324): error C7510: 'Callback': use of dependent template name must be prefixed with 'template'
```

Follows code which is referenced by the error messages:

```
// Construct a COM/WinRT delegate (an object with an Invoke() method) from a lambda.
// Check the return from this function for null to detect out of memory (E_OUTOFMEMORY) failure case.
template<typename TDelegateInterface, typename TLambda>
ComPtr<typename Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>::Interface> Callback(TLambda&& callback) throw()
{
    using DelegateHelper = Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>;
    return DelegateHelper::Traits::Callback<TDelegateInterface, typename DelegateHelper::Interface>(Details::Forward<TLambda>(callback));
}

// Construct a COM/WinRT delegate, an object with an Invoke() method, from a raw function.
template<typename TDelegateInterface, typename TFunc> ComPtr<typename Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>::Interface> Callback(_In_ TFunc* callback) throw()
{
    using DelegateHelper = Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>;
    return DelegateHelper::Traits::Callback<TDelegateInterface, typename DelegateHelper::Interface>(
    [=](auto&& ...args) {
        return callback(Details::Forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    });
}
```

Honestly, I've got any idea, what's wrong. Since last update, this particular code was working (as far as I know). Would you please point me to the solution?

I understand that it has something to do with dependent template names. But I don't know what part of code is wrong - if it's some kind of typo in `winrt` or they changed something lately and I have to adjust my code.

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: They changed the rules and no longer accept code without `template` for dependent templates. It is `event.h` that has to be fixed.

Comment: @Evg thank you, you were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Evg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52140771/c-windows-notification-use-of-dependent-template-name?noredirect=1#comment91231328_52140771) pointed out, they probably made some changes and keyword `template` is now required for dependent teplates.

If someone is wondering, this is the new code in `event.h`, which seems to be working:

```
// Construct a COM/WinRT delegate (an object with an Invoke() method) from a lambda.
// Check the return from this function for null to detect out of memory (E_OUTOFMEMORY) failure case.
template<typename TDelegateInterface, typename TLambda>
ComPtr<typename Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>::Interface> Callback(TLambda&& callback) throw()
{
    using DelegateHelper = Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>;
    return DelegateHelper::Traits::template Callback<TDelegateInterface, typename DelegateHelper::Interface>(Details::Forward<TLambda>(callback));
}

// Construct a COM/WinRT delegate, an object with an Invoke() method, from a raw function.
template<typename TDelegateInterface, typename TFunc>
ComPtr<typename Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>::Interface> Callback(_In_ TFunc* callback) throw()
{
    using DelegateHelper = Details::DelegateArgTraitsHelper<TDelegateInterface>;
    return DelegateHelper::Traits::template Callback<TDelegateInterface, typename DelegateHelper::Interface>(
    [=](auto&& ...args)
    {
        return callback(Details::Forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    });
}
```